# $ionicLoading loading forever

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to show ionic loader until my data is received but somehow its loading forever. I checked some solutions but did not work. This is my code.

$ionicLoading.show({
            content: 'Loading',
            animation: 'fade-in',
            showBackdrop: true,
            maxWidth: 200,
            showDelay: 0
        });

```
    $scope.allcourses = CourseFactory.FindFreeCourses($scope.search).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        $scope.allfreestadiums = result;
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Network Error',
            scope: $scope
        });
        $timeout(function() {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        }, 100);
    })
```

When I call only

$scope.allcourses = CourseFactory.FindFreeCourses($scope.search);

It's working fine but I want to show a loading before it appears on the screen.
What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

console.log() may behave differently on a device/emulator than on a browser. While a browser will typically accept any object as a param, as console.log(obj), this is problematic on devices. You may want to try this instead: 
`console.log("some message", JSON.stringify(obj))`

```
$ionicLoading.show({ content: 'Loading', animation: 'fade-in', showBackdrop: true, maxWidth: 200, showDelay: 0 });

$scope.allcourses = CourseFactory.FindFreeCourses($scope.search).then(function(result){
  $ionicLoading.hide();
  $scope.allfreestadiums = result;
  console.log("success", JSON.stringify(result));
}, function(error){
  $ionicLoading.hide();
  console.log("error", JSON.stringify(error));
})
```

It is also possible that the console.log() function is failing because console is not defined when called. It depends on how you are testing and if the environment exposes the console variable by default. It's a bit of a Schrodinger scenario - the act of opening the dev console makes the problem go away because the console variable is defined when you do that on some browsers. Try commenting out the console.log() calls and move $ionicLoading.hide() to the top of those callbacks.

Or you can check that window.console exists before calling console.log() as shown here:

```
$ionicLoading.show({ content: 'Loading', animation: 'fade-in', showBackdrop: true, maxWidth: 200, showDelay: 0 });

$scope.allcourses = CourseFactory.FindFreeCourses($scope.search).then(function(result){
  $ionicLoading.hide();
  window.console && console.log("success", JSON.stringify(result));
  $scope.allfreestadiums = result;
}, function(error){
  $ionicLoading.hide();
  window.console && console.log("error", JSON.stringify(error));
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but i tried all the things u mentioned but still its loading forever. I removed the console.log, put the hide on top of the callback still didnt work. Is it maybe a browser issue or from the factory method? because if i call only $scope.allcourses = CourseFactory.FindFreeCourses($scope.search) it is working fine.

Comment: Have you worked with Angular promises much?  CourseFactory.FindFreeCourses() will need to return a promise, and that promise must be resolved in order to work. My guess is that in FindFreeCourses() you aren't resolving the promise, which is necessary to reach any of those .then() callbacks. Inside FindFreeCourses(), be sure to do something like: `var q = $q.defer();   /* do your course lookup callback */  q.resolve();  /* ... */  return q.promise;`